# Replace columns in pyspark dataframe after join

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have the below 2 dataframes.
col_1 col_2 col_3 belongs to dataframe 1 and col_4 col_5 and col_6 belongs to dataframe 2.
Join has to performed on col_1 from df1 and col_4 from df2 and its a "left" join

dataframe 1

```
col_1   col_2   col_3   col_3a
a       NA      NA      A
b       NA      NA      B
c       NA      NA      C
d       NA      NA      D
```

dataframe 2

```
col_4   col_5   col_6
a       1       1
b       1       1
c       1       1
```

Output dataframe should be in the format:

```
col_1   col_2   col_3    col_3a
a       1       1        A
b       1       1        B
c       1       1        C
d       NA      NA       D
```

Essentially, the col_5 and col_6 values should be replaced in dataframe 1 - col_2 and col_3 when a match is available. 
I tried with withcolumnrenamed and was not much successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`coalesce`**](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-regular-functions.html#coalesce) function to get `first not null` value from **col_5,col_2** and **col_6,col_3**

**`Example:`**

```
df1.join(df2,df1.col_1 == df2.col_4,'left').\
selectExpr("col_1","coalesce(col_5,col_2) as col_2","coalesce(col_6,col_3) as col_3","col_3a").\
orderBy("col_1").\
show()
#+-----+-----+-----+------+
#|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_3a|
#+-----+-----+-----+------+
#|    a|    1|    1|     A|
#|    b|    1|    1|     B|
#|    c|    1|    1|     C|
#|    d|   NA|   NA|     D|
#+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: THere is a possibility that col_2 and col_3 can have values other than NA. THats why i didnt use coalesce. Whatever the value in col_2 and col_3 i have to replace it with values from col_5 and col_6 when a match is found

Comment: @shankar, in coalesce if we have `null` value exists for `col_5`(no match found) then we are replacing with `col_2` other wise we are always getting **col_5** values if match found.

Comment: THanks for reply. Agreed.. But even col_5 has NA, i have to still replace col_2 with NA from col_5. its replace the entire column no matter what scenario

Comment: @shankar, try with this `df1.join(df2,df1.col_1 == df2.col_4,'left').withColumn("col_2", when(col("col_5").isNull(),col("col_2")).otherwise(col("col_5"))).withColumn("col_3",when(col("col_6").isNull(),col("col_3")).otherwise(col("col_6"))).select("col_1","col_2","col_3","col_3a").orderBy("col_1").show()` let me know if it satisfies the scenario!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have in mind is to merge the two dataset with different suffixes and apply a `case_when` afterwards. The solution is untested.

First, perform a full join: (in your example a left join is enough)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

df_join = (df1
            .join(df2, psf.col('col_1') == psf.col('col_4'), how = "full_outer")
            .drop("col_4")
           )
```

I assumed you wanted a `full join`. You can change if needed.

Then, you use conditional replacement with `psf.when`

```py
df_join = df_join
    .withColumn("col_2",
            psf.when(psf.col('col_2').isNull(),
                     psf.col('col_5'))
                     )
                 )
    .withColumn("col_3",
            psf.when(psf.col('col_2').isNull(),
                     psf.col('col_6'))
                     )
                 )
```